# how to write this block of code without repeating myself?

Tags: javascript

Having a huge brain fart right now...

I am writing a little stock price tracker and instead of making multiple API requests, I save the data into my localStorage with a timestamp.
If I search for the same stock, it looks into my localStorage for the item.

If the stock **doesnt** exist in my localStorage, it makes a fetch request to the API.

If the stock **does** exist, it checks the current time as well as the timestamp when the stock was saved.

If the stock timestamp **does** exceed the limit, it makes a fetch request.

If the stock timestamp **doesn't** exceed the limit, it grabs the data from localStorage.

This is the code I have so far:

```
let info = await retrieve_ticker_info( 'aapl' ) 

let retrieve_ticker_info = async ( ticker ) => {

    return new Promise( resolve => {

        let data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( `${ticker}` ) )

        if ( data ) {
            // IF SAVED DATA IS NOT NULL
            if ( data.expiration < Date.now() ) {
                // IF SAVED DATA IS EXPIRED
                fetch( api_url )
                    .then( res => res.json() )
                    .then( res => {
                        data = { ...res, expiration: Date.now() + TIME_TIL_REFRESH }
                        localStorage.setItem( `${ticker}`, JSON.stringify( data ) )
                        resolve( data )
                    })
            } else {
                // IF SAVED DATA IS NOT EXPIRED
                resolve( data )
            }

        } else {
            // IS DATA IS NULL
            fetch( api_url )
                .then( res => res.json() )
                .then( res => {
                    data = { ...res, expiration: Date.now() + TIME_TIL_REFRESH }
                    localStorage.setItem( `${ticker}`, JSON.stringify( data ) )
                    resolve( data )
                })
        }
    })
}
```

With this, I would have to rewrite the fetch and that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Create a `fetchData` function with `ticker` and `api_url` as parameters?

Comment: Yea thats a solution but I wrote this function with the intent to grab all the information. When I submit my form, it runs a function called: `search_ticker(ticker)` which calls `retrieve_ticker_info(ticker)`. Kinda didnt want to write another func. But if thats the only solution, then I guess I have to.

Comment: Generally we write functions when we don't want to repeat ourselves. So I don't get why you're hesitant. Is there some other problem as well?

Comment: Sorry for the tangent, but I couldn't help but notice you're not using `await` for your `fetch` calls.

Comment: @JacobHeater didnt know you needed to await fetch calls. EDIT: tested it out real quick and I get this error: `await is only valid in async function`. I don't believe it's necessary.

Comment: @syn I posted an example below. You don't *need* to `await` anything. It's just nice to have it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
(async () => {

  let info = await retrieve_ticker_info('aapl');

  let fetch_data = async (api_url, ticker) => {
    const res = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = {
      ...res.json(),
      expiration: Date.now() + TIME_TIL_REFRESH
    };

    localStorage.setItem(`${ticker}`, JSON.stringify(data));

    return data;
  };

  let retrieve_ticker_info = async (ticker) => {

    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${ticker}`));

    if (data) {
      // IF SAVED DATA IS NOT NULL
      if (data.expiration < Date.now()) {
        data = await fetch_data(api_url, ticker);
      }

    } else {
      // IS DATA IS NULL
      data = await fetch_data(api_url, ticker);
    }

    return data;
  };

})();
```

Edit: Updated the code to wrap it in an `async` IIFE.

Comment: `await` can't be used outside `async` functions. It's probably worth mentioning that the function that `let info = await retrieve_ticker_info('aapl');` should be within an `async` function.

Comment: I don't disagree. I simply copied the original code. I'll update for clarity.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Updated with an async IIFE.